# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 in web server

Tags: java, exception

I have made a simple RESTful web service using tomcat web container and jersey library.

I have overridden only post method, rest all default settings are used.

While sending `POST` query from `curl` from server machine I get expected response. From other machine also, I am getting expected response for `GET` query, but for `POST` I get `java.lang.` `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` exception error. The post method goes like this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String post(String str) {
  String[] parts = str.split("&");
  String[] param1 = parts[0].split("=");//value1=param1[1] (one/two): query type
  String[] param2 = parts[1].split("=");//value2=param2[1] 
  String[] param3 = parts[2].split("=");//value3=param3[1] 
  String[] param4 = parts[3].split("=");//value4=param4[1] 

  if(param1[1].equals("one")){
      return hashGenerator(param2[1],param3[1]);
  }else if(param1[1].equals("two")){
      return saveInput(param2[1],param3[1],param4[1]);
  }
  return "Unexpected Query";
}
```

Response from server is :

```
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:421)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

root cause

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
com.va.jersey.helloworld.Hello.post(Hello.java:39)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:164)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:181)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
  org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

can you please suggest likely fault....

Comment: post your `com.va.jersey.helloworld.Hello` i mean the code specially the post method.

Comment: one of your `split` is not giving you 2 array positions....

Comment: when i give command `curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4&" http://myAddr......../.../.....` i'm getting correct response

Comment: my sincere request ....please tell the  reason for down grading question....atleast i'll not repeat it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for array elements which might not exist, so splitting that input string on a character and not checking the length of the array always risks throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to use these non-existent array elements later (an input string of `foo&bar` would do it).

Furthermore, you should never do the form data / query string parsing yourself, there are too many edge cases. Use a library, or better still use your framework (Jersey) - it, as part of JAX-RS, has [support for Form Params](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.0/jersey/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html). See [an example here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/).

Or you could make it more RESTful and use [PathParam](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html)s to take parameters explicitly in the request, if that's an option.